# Record raw Audio from mic to Base64 string

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-audio-api, web-mediarecorder, audiocontext

My current aim is to record a 3-5s bit of raw audio material using the device's microphone and converting this into an encoded base64 string of byte[]. The audio itself is required to be mono sound and in 44100Hz to be compatible with the API i am using.

My current approach using the MediaRecorder seems to force me to  attach some kind of coded and container as soon as i assemble the Blob from the gathered stream. Another alternative, since i dont require a file output is the use of the AudioContext by attaching a MediaStreamAudioSourceNode to it, but i have difficulty processing the incoming data from this approach.

Below the current approach based on MediaRecorder:

```
  public readonly arrayBufferToBase64 = (arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer) => {
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    let base64String = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
      base64String += String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i]);
    }
    return btoa(base64String);
  };

  public readonly audioSetup = async () => {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: {
            channelCount: 1,
            sampleRate: 44100,
          },
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
          const chunks: BlobPart[] | undefined = [];

          recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", function (e) {
            chunks.push(e.data);
          });

          recorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
            const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/wav" });
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            // const audio = new Audio();
            // audio.src = url;
            // audio.play();

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
              console.log(
                this.arrayBufferToBase64(reader.result as ArrayBuffer)
              );
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
          });

          // Start recording
          recorder.start();

          // Stop recording after 3 seconds
          setTimeout(function () {
            recorder.stop();
          }, 5000);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.error("Error accessing microphone:", err);
        });
    } else {
      console.error("MediaRecorder API not supported");
    }
```